# Why is the Schwarz Lemma not formulated for arbitrary radius $R$, maximum $M$ and radius center $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In its traditional formulation, $R=1$, $M=1$ and $z_0=0$. But it is also true for arbitrary $R$, $M$  and $z_0$, as it can be seen in here under number "2": https://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/classes/ma416/s09.pdf. And because theorems are usually formulated in the broadest sense possible, which would make them most applicable, it created confusion in me at first. Why is that? Is this because it's a lemma? I haven't gotten to where the Schwarz Lemma is being used yet.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what i've observed is that theorems are formulated in a such a way, that one can always ask "what happens if i change or ignore that condition?" and arrive to a better understanding when they understand why the theorem doesn't hold then, and that's what i usually try to do.

Comment: @nicomezi I guess. I always feel sort of weird about the soft questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just more elegant to phrase it on the unit disk. The modification to arbitrary disks is completely elementary and thus, doesn't really give the statement any more depth. So no, we don't always state propositions in full generality, if full generality means capturing every direct application in the phrasing of the result.